# Manga set in a magical world where a strong girl befriends a disguised prince and becomes a magic knight

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

So, probably about ten years ago, I read this manga, less than ten books in total, about a girl who was really strong and I think wanted to become a knight but was not good at it because of her strength.

She befriended this person in town who encouraged her to keep at it and he turned out to be the crown prince. She eventually ended up being pivotal in the princes’ lives because the younger prince was very frail but had a lot of magic that you needed strength to wield, and when some ministers attempted a coup with the younger prince, she was able to use her strength to avert a disaster.

I could’ve sworn the title talked about some kind of semi-precious stone like turquoise or jade but I don’t really remember.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Is the female knight the protagonist, and the prince a (possible) love interest for her? You mention she's too strong to become a knight. How does that work? Does she repeatedly break her weapons or something else?

Comment: Is there a chance this is novel? The plot match 90% like a light novel I read. Plot also match but I don't think there is manga nor 10 volume

Comment: "Shounin Yuusha wa Isekai wo Gyuujiru! - Saibai Skill de Nandemo Fuyashi Chaimasu" has the female lead be so strong she breaks weapons and thus was useless as an adventurer, but nothing else matches at all.